# FaceTime hijacked

Tags: facetime

A friend of mine just called me to say she got a FaceTime call with my name showing. When she answered it was someone completely different. She called me asking who the person was calling from my FaceTime. I told her I had no idea what she was talking about. We then went on FaceTime so I could show her where I was. While on FaceTime she got another FaceTime call with my address showing. She hung up with me to answer it and it was the same person again. She even screen printed the person's image for me.

What is going on?

Comment: Plot for a bad science fiction movie...

Comment: Other than the suggestion of the account being hacked, what else could be going on, I had the same problem and immediatly changed my password, but the problem persists.

Comment: This happened to me the other morning. My boyfriend called,
Lost connection I went to FaceTime back and then it was an old last who
Answered...? Had my boyfriend
Call me back and then it was him.. Yet the number I called back was my boyfriends number

Comment: This is still happening. Between Monday and today someone else got access to our family share account and FaceTime called them by mistake. The calls at 3:26pm, 3:28pm, and 3:30pm all went to this thief. Apple doesn't see anyone else having logged in, so I'm wondering if sessions can be cloned or something. This was not an innocent person — he covered the camera and wouldn't identify himself, and did not even ask who I was. Can't Apple figure out what device received those connections? (Email privately supplied placed the calls) We changed pws and got him locked out but clearly there is a vulne

Comment: (privately supplied to apple I mean, of course :P)

Answer (score 5):

Your Apple account may have been compromised. Change all your passwords immediately, and don't use the same password on multiple accounts or websites.