# Can one's iMessage/FaceTime identities be hijacked at a public Wi-Fi?

Tags: macos, messages, security, facetime

I'm logged in on "Joe's MacBook Pro" at a public Wi-Fi.

I get an alert window (apparently from no program in particular). It says:

> Your Apple ID is now being used for iMessage and FaceTime on a new Mac.
>
> If you recently signed into “Joe's MacBook Pro” you can ignore this notification.

What does this mean? I use several development tools (Emacs, …) but neither iMessage nor FaceTime.

I never use the same password twice as suggested as an answer to [FaceTime hijacked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104916/7985), nor do I otherwise have a reason to believe my Apple (macOS or iCloud) account is compromised.

Is this a security risk? The message does not indicate what to do if I had *not* "recently signed into".

**Please provide some back-up or reference for your answer, so as not to trigger extra caution when none is needed.** *The point is to understand what's happening, not to be prudent just to be on the safe side.*

Comment: Was it asking your for credentials or is it just an alert?

Comment: @fsb No. It was just an alert. It wasn't asking for any credentials. One reason I'm uncomfortable is that AirDrop showed up in OS X at some point, and, conveniently, Finder now says under AirDrop: "To share with someone using a Mac, ask them to go to AirDrop in the Finder." But I don't quite have a grasp of what this is about.

Comment: I would recommend immediately changing your Apple ID password while you research this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm. If you have more than one Mac, and stop using one for a while, macOS will give you this warning. The duration of absence can be, empirically, as little as two months.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this **may** be a security risk. But it's unlikely that someone hijacked your Mac using Wi-Fi alone.

In order for you to receive this message someone needs to login with your Apple ID credentials with a device that supports FaceTime (iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, any Mac).

---

### Change your Apple ID password

1. Go to [Manage Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/signin)
2. Log in with your Apple ID
3. Go to Security > "Change Password..."
4. Change your password
5. Also turn on two-factor authentication if it isn't already

---

### Check your Devices

1. Go to [Manage Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/signin)
2. Log in with your Apple ID
3. Scroll down to *My Devices*
4. Click any device that looks unfamiliar to you
5. In the new window **click the blue circle with an x** to remove it.

---

You may need to sign in with your new Apple ID password on your other devices in order to use all iCloud services again.

Comment: That's good. But I'm really looking to hunt down what's happening. On a unix system, for instance, if you're wondering if someone is grabbing your screen, there is a multitude of commands (simplest: `who`, next simplest: `top`) you can run to figure out whether someone else. Is there anything I can do in such a case to determine the damage that has been done? If I rush to "check your devices" as you outline, I should see the invader, if any. Is that right?

Comment: FaceTime is a service that's managed by iCloud. If someone gets his/her hands on your Apple ID and password, this person connects to Apple servers. If access will be granted, all your connected devices get a notification about this. So **this person does not need to have access to your device, only your Apple ID credentials**. Even if a someone connected to you device to grab your credentials, he/she would close any connection to your device before signing in with them. /// Yes, if you check your devices the device will be visible there.